# Write a list containing data frames into excel file using parallel processing

Tags: r, parallel-processing, xlsx

Can we write a list containing data frames as excel worksheets in single workbook using parallel processing.

Currently I am doing this using for loop and using xlsx package. But its taking around 2 minutes for 150 sheets.

> EDIT- Added my code sample with two data frames in a list

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1=c(1,2,3),y2=c(4,5,6))
d2 <- data.frame(y1=c(3,2,1),y2=c(6,5,4))
list_df <- list(d1, d2)

for(i in 1: length(list_df)){
  write.xlsx(list_df[[i]], file="sample.xlsx", sheetName=paste0("sheet ", i), append = T, row.names=F, col.names = F )

}
```

I am trying to optimize time for this using parallel computing. But don't know how to apply it in this case.

Comment: You can't write to one file in parallel.

Comment: then is there a faster way to do it??

Comment: It would be helpful for you to add your current code you are using to do this.

Comment: @akaDrHouse I have updated question with my code sample having two data frames in a list. As I said I have list with 150 data frames which is to be written to excel file.

Comment: Are these large files? Does the sum of time needed to do each one come close to the two minutes needed to do all?  I don't know of a better way to do it. Even if you used foreach to concurrently write multiple files, you may just be hitting your hard drive write limits.

Comment: yes its taking that much time or even more time if data frame sizes increases. I am creating that list of 150 data frames using some calculations in 2 minutes, and after that writing these in 2 minutes is frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to write to a Excel file in parallel with R with the following code :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
path_Excel_File_Output <- "D:\\test.xlsx"

list_df <- list()

for(i in 1 : 20)
{
  if(i %% 2 == 0)
  {
    list_df[[i]] <- data.frame(y1 = c(1,2,3), y2 = c(4,5,6))
    
  }else
  {
    list_df[[i]] <- data.frame(y1 = c(3,2,1), y2 = c(6,5,4))
  }
}

nb_CPU <- 10
cluster <- parallel::makeCluster(nb_CPU)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl = cluster)

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open("D:\\test.xlsx")
Sheets <- xlWbk$Sheets()

for(i in 1 : 20)
{
  Sheets$Add()
}

fn_Par <- function(i, list_df)
{
    library(RDCOMClient)
    xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
    xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
    xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open("D:\\test.xlsx")

    Sheets <- xlWbk$Sheets() 
    nb_Row <- dim(list_df[[i]])[1]
    nb_Col <- dim(list_df[[i]])[2]
    col_End_Range <- LETTERS[nb_Col]
    row_End_Range <- nb_Row
    range_To_Write <- paste0("A1:", col_End_Range, row_End_Range, collapse = "")
    obj_Range <- Sheets[[i]]$Range(range_To_Write)
    obj_Range[["Value"]] <- asCOMArray(list_df[[i]])
}

parLapply(cluster, X = 1 : 20, fun = fn_Par,  list_df = list_df)
```

This code writes the 20 data.frame in parallel in the Excel file D:\test.xlsx.