# Improving upload speed to excel in r

Tags: r, excel

I have a code that downloads csv files and uploads them to Excel workbook.

Now, each csv file is 60MB+, so the upload process is quite slow. I would like to know how can I improve the process(by using another library or piece of code, either work). Here is a dummy code (I would also like to know if I can improve the code itself since it is quite repetitive):

```
library(openxlsx)
library(data.table)


wb<-loadWorkbook("Output.xlsx")
jun18<-fread("June18.csv")
writeData(wb,sheet="Jun18",jun18)
may18<-fread("May18.csv")
writeData(wb,sheet="May18",may18)
apr18<-fread("Apr18.csv")
writeData(wb,sheet="Apr18",apr18)
mar18<-fread("Mar18.csv")
writeData(wb,sheet="Mar18",mar18)
feb18<-fread("Feb18.csv")
writeData(wb,sheet="Feb18",feb18)
jan18<-fread("Jan18.csv")
writeData(wb,sheet="Jan18",jan18)
dec17<-fread("Dec17.csv")
writeData(wb,sheet="Dec17",dec17)
nov17<-fread("Nov17.csv")
writeData(wb,sheet="Nov17",nov17)
oct17<-fread("Oct17.csv")
writeData(wb,sheet="Oct17",oct17)
sep17<-fread("Sep17.csv")
writeData(wb,sheet="Sep17",sep17)
aug17<-fread("Aug17.csv")
writeData(wb,sheet="Aug17",aug17)
jul17<-fread("Jul17.csv")
writeData(wb,sheet="Jul17",jul17)
jun17<-fread("Jun17.csv")
writeData(wb,sheet="Jun17",jun17)
#It took 7 min to get to this point
saveWorkbook(wb,"Output.xlsx",overwrite=TRUE)
#It took another 21 min to get to the end
```

Comment: Excel really isn't optimized for creating workbooks approaching 1GB in size. If you must use Excel, why not different workbooks for different csv files? Also, why do this at all? Excel can directly open csv files without needing them to be manually copied into worksheets.

Comment: @JohnColeman This would summarise 1 out of 12 sections I need to work with. The idea is to create the database using R. I am currently looking into Shiny to see if it will do the trick. In case it will not, the Excel is the only option (don't have SQL for that)

Comment: Excel is not a database. Why not use Access (if you are an Office user) or an open-source alternative?

Comment: I would agree with John, Excel is not your friend on this task. If you would rather avoid complicated databases or expensive tools, SQLite is free and works nicely for small projects.

Comment: So instead of uploading it to Excel, it will upload to SQL? If that's so what package(s) am I looking at? @JMenezes

Comment: Package DBI can handle interactions with database. My knowledge is a little rusty on it but something the two functions dbconnect() and createtable() do what you want. Creating a database in sqlite is a single command line instruction (if I recall correctly `sqlite3 -i databasename.sql`, or something similar).

Comment: I would recommend writing a short script to read each `.csv` file, add a column for date, (i.e. file name), combine them as a single data frame, then either upload to a database, or export as your format of choice.

Answer (score 0):

You could increase the number of threads using the following approach.

```
fread("June18.csv", nThread = 10)
```

Also, you could separate the reading of the csv file and the writing of the Excel files. Maybe you could consider writing Excel sheets in parallel to increase the writing speed : [Write a list containing data frames into excel file using parallel processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40087034/write-a-list-containing-data-frames-into-excel-file-using-parallel-processing/73930830#73930830)

To sum up, you could 1) increase the nThread to increase the reading speed 2) write the data.frame in parallel in the Excel file once all the CSV files have been loaded in memory.